# Dispensation of digital pics

Tags: java, image-processing

I have a project named dispensation of digi pics which should be done using java, but I have a doubt that "dispensation of digi pics" and "digital image processing" are same or not.

If not please tell me what is meant by dispensation of digi pics and how can I move further with the project.

Comment: Hi Rams, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question is hard to answer. The definition of Dispensation is "to dispense." How did you get this project? Can you ask whomever gave you this project for clarification?

Comment: If it was widely used jargon, Google would find a definition somewhere - but I found hardly any references to "photo dispensation" and most of those referred to the legal thing of getting permission from models etc to publish the photos. I suppose it could refer to some kind of "have I got rights to publish and a model release for these photos" mini-database, though.

Comment: It sounds like someone is given a freelance project that he can't understand.

Answer (score 5):

> i have a project named dispensation of digi pics which should be done using java...but i have a doubt that "dispensation of digi pics" and "digital image processing" are same or not.

I agree that they are probably not the same thing, but my opinion is irrelevant.

You should ask whoever gave you this project to do to explain to you what **they** really meant.

No amount of asking other people is going to answer that question for you.